# Can I have multiple 'it' in one 'describe' and use a beforeEach

Tags: cypress

So, I have a beforeEach to load up my site. I am mainly writing my test in one `describe` function with one `it` function.

my beforeEach is in the index.js>Support>Cypress folder

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/');
});
```

Current Code Example:

```
describe('this is a test',function(){
    it('will be a test example',function(){
        cy.contains('test').click
        cy.contains('another test').click()
    })
})
```

A co worker pointed out that I should try to break them up to be more clear on what each test is doing so long as each part can run independently. I have several tests that can run independent, however, the beforeEach kicks in for each `it('test_name',function()` I write.

For example: I write a test to open a card, click on a state, add data about that state, then close. If I break each part into it's own `it` then it will have the beforeEach start back on the "home" page of my site.

Example of desired code:

```
describe('this is a test',function(){
    it('will be a test example',function(){
        cy.contains('test').click
    })
    it('will test another test',function(){
        cy.contains('another test').click()
    })
})
```

Is there a way for those several `it` functions to continue on the previous test rather than having the beforeEach effect it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `beforeEach()` and `before()`. The behaviour of both is slightly different.
`before()` only applies once per `describe()`
`beforeEach()`applies for every `it()` in the `describe()`

Thus what you have to do:
Put all steps you want to only perform once per `describe()`in a `before()`. If there are still steps left which you want to perform every `it()`, put those in a `beforeEach()`.

Note that you can use both `before()` and `beforeEach()` together.

Comment: thank you! This clarified a lot for me and how I will write my future tests. :)